# What is the default username and password to the oracle pre-built virtual machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I downloaded [DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/virtualbox/dd/DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html and successfully loaded it into Virtual Box.

I logged in as "oracle" user and I can see the desktop.

From within the virtual machine, I opened Firefox and navigated to:

http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/employees/ and successfully received a list of employees in JSON format. So I know the database is up and running.

My only problem is I cannot login to the database.

I tried:

```
[oracle@vbgeneric oracle]$ sqlplus oracle

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Jul 5 17:32:22 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: oracle
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:
```

my ORACLE_SID=orcl12c

How do I login to the database itself?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2238643?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default password for the `HR`, `sys` and `system` accounts is `oracle`.

The Unix password for the oracle user is also `oracle`.

Comment: did the following:  sqlplus hr  and entered "oracle" as password and it worked.

Comment: three years later, for Oracle 12.2 vm image, for unix account `oracle`, the `oracle` password doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 6):

Okay, this is probably a better answer, since the objective is to be able to work with the 'system' database.

Use:
    sqlplus system as sysdba

and the password is -> oracle

> I got in using student / student.  This was in the Getting Started
>   with EDQ pdf document, but it was not clearly designated that it
>   worked for the sqlplus login.
>
> ```
> [oracle@edqtrn ~]$ sqlplus system
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Sat Aug 11 10:12:39 2018
>     Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Enter password: 
> ERROR:
> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
>
> Enter user-name: student
>
> Enter password: 
>
> Last Successful login time: Fri Aug 10 2018 23:57:35 -04:00
>
> Connected to:
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
> With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
>
> SQL>
> ```

Comment: Actually, `sqlplus sys as sysdba` than connecting with `system` would be better, but both are more dangerous than a regular user ID.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to login to the database as follows:

```
sqlplus sys/oracle@localhost/orcl12c as sysdba
```

Comment: sqlplus sys as sysdba    ... worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle Database System Privileges Accounts and Passwords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/oracle-database-system-privileges-accounts-and-passwords.html#GUID-7513171C-1055-48BB-8C79-B27EECC9B7E9), all databases created by the Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA) include the SYS, SYSTEM, and DBSNMP database accounts, where

- **SYS** is the account used to perform database administration tasks
- **SYSTEM** is another account used to perform database administration tasks
- **DBSNMP** is the account used by the Management Agent component of Oracle Enterprise Manager to monitor and manage the database

When trying connect with **SYS**, I got `ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER`, but connecting with **SYSTEM** worked.

The default password might be `oracle`, but should have actually been set during configuration.